# Static text with scrollbar win32

Tags: c++, winapi

Hi guys I'm trying to make static text with a scrollbar. I created a scrollbar window with editable text this way:

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", text, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL| ES_AUTOVSCROLL, posX, posY, width, height, parWindow, HMENU(ID), hinstance, NULL);
```

and it is working properly, but when I do the same thing and change the `"EDIT"` to `"STATIC"`, the scrollbar stop working. Any ideas without using `WM_SCROLL` message?

Comment: [Static controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-static-controls) do not provide scroll bars. You should consider asking about the problem rather than what you hope to be part of the solution.

Comment: It is also recommended that you use `read-only edit control`. After setting the border of [edit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls) to 0, the display is consistent with static text. [The renderings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft8lB.png).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware the static control does not honor scroll messages (I checked the wine sources and the static control file does not have the string "scroll" anywhere), you will have to implement this yourself.

Note that instead of a static control, you might want to consider a read-only edit control. You could still get edit's scroll handling that way.

Comment: read-only property works